# error while uploading csv file to mysql database from RMysql package

Tags: mysql, shiny, rmysql

I am developing a shiny app where user can upload a csv file and then it will be pushed to mysql database. I am using RMysql package for doing this task.

```
db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host = host, 
              port = port, user = user, password = password)

    dbSendQuery(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS web_domain (

          domain_name VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
          create_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
          expiry_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_name VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_company VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_address VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_city VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_state VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_zip VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_country VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_email VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          registrant_phone VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT NULL,
          email VARCHAR(70) DEFAULT NULL,
          domain VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
          domain_company VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
          reg_years VARCHAR(12) DEFAULT NULL

          )"
        )
```

First I am creating a table structure in mysql. My csv file also has exactly the same column names as of table schema. When I try to upload csv file it gives me following error.

```
Warning: Closing open result sets

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5044
Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
Warning: Closing open result sets
Warning: Error in .local: could not run statement: Unknown column     'row_names' in 'field list'
Stack trace (innermost first):
74: .local
73: dbSendQuery
72: dbSendQuery
71: dbGetQuery
70: dbGetQuery
69: .local
68: dbWriteTable
67: dbWriteTable
66: saveData [functions.R#109]
65: observeEventHandler [E:\R Project\TITBIT\Titbit_Dash/server.R#61]
 1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

I am not able to figure out what does it mean by `unknown column row_names` in `field_list` and I want to append the data from csv file everytime user uploads a new csv file.

Please help.

Comment: What's your CSV file?  Issue could be in there, as this looks like a runtime error, and not a compile time error.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Once I upload a csv file,I pass it through a function which cleans the file and later on I upload it to database. csv file is with headers same as that of database column names. Will it cause error?